# different outcomes in one cell in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to get the following to happen in excel but I am a novice with excel.

if the "cell"<27,700=£8,355,if the "cell">27,700 but <37,970 then "cell" -27,700/2= answer, if cell>27,700, "cell">37,970=£3,220

the "cell" and the formula and so outcome/answer would be in another cell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use nested [`if`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

```
=IF(A1<27700,8335,IF(A1<37970,-27700/2,3220))
```

Basically you check the lowest possible that way it won't go to the next `if` if it's true. Then the next lowest etc. If you start with the highest then everything will return `TRUE`.